# Is it possible for Paperclip to generate a new image (with no source)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm building an image based off of user input -- the background will either be an image or a color, and then a few other images may or may not be composed on top.

Checking through the paperclip docs, it mentions that you can use ImageMagik to *post-process* images, and that post-processing will never fire if it doesnt already have an image.

If I am able to make the imagemagik scripts to compose/color/resize an image, is there a way for it to *generate* the image, or will I need to include some sort of hackish pixel to upload (and then postprocess in to the image I want)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following:

- Have a default image in my app's assets folder
- If the model to be saved has no attachment then I would assign it the one mentioned above: `a_model.image = File.open('...')`
- Then, upon save of the `a_model` the post-processing should take place normally

Answer (score 4):

ImageMagick can generate a starting image for you, consisting of a simple rectangle filled with a single color.  For example, this will generate a 150x100 red image:

```
convert -size 150x100 xc:"#ff0000" starting_image.png
```

Comment: Yep, but paperclip will only reference/call to imagemagick in *post processing*, which means I need an image to begin with beforehand.

Comment: I played around with something sort of like this, but ran in to an issue where paperclip complained about the image having an empty mime type; it appears to be a longstanding bug with paperclip and aws-sdk. I ended up having to use a starting pixel.

Comment: Using a 1x1 starting image should work.  I don't have any recent experience with Paperclip.  It was my main word processor about 40 years ago on my Commodore 64, long before mime types even existed.